# How to determine a map which sends $(1,-1,0)\to(\infty,0,i)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I know that the uninque bilinear map sending $(z_1,z_2,z_3)\to (\infty,0,1)$ is given by $$T(z)=\frac{(z-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}{(z-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}.$$ Well, could any one tell me how to determine a map which sends $(1,-1,0)\to(\infty,0,i)$?

Comment: Lars Ahlfors' Complex Analysis Section 3.2 on the Cross Ratio explains how to do this immediately after Theorem 12 on page 79.

Comment: What do you mean when you say $T$ is bilinear?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $T$ is a map which sends $(-1, 1, 0)$ to $(\infty, 0, 1)$. Now let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Note that $\lambda\infty = \infty$, and $\lambda 0 = 0$ so $\lambda T$ sends $(-1, 1, 0)$ to $(\infty, 0, \lambda)$. Now choose $\lambda$ appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You know how to find maps to $(\infty, 0, 1)$. Have you thought how that might that be used in your quest?

Answer (score 0):

Got one theorem saying The Unique Bi-Linear Map $w=f(z)$ which sends $w_1,w_2,w_3\to z_1,z_2,z_3$ is given by $$\frac{(w-w_2)(w_3-w_1)}{(w-w_1)(w_3-w_2)}=\frac{(z-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}{(z-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}$$